# Thingsboard push button to device from dashboard

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, thingsboard

I'm using Thingsboard on cloud and thingsboard gateway on my raspberry pi.

How can i send and receive push of a button from the dashboard to a device connected, and read it's status?

`| tb | tb-gw | device |
| ---------------> ?? |
| ?? <--------------- |`

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked this guide https://thingsboard.io/docs/iot-gateway/mqtt/#server-side-rpc-commands ?

Comment: I have used system control switch in my dashboard but the switch doesn't move at all. I create a script to replace request to response of course. Seems like a device (son of a gateway) doesn't consider the rpc.